# Cognos Analytics server installation file does not show license agreement

Tags: cognos

I am installing Cognos Analytics server by right clicking on the setup file and running as administrator. But I can't continue because it does not show me the license agreement and the option to accept it.

I have Windows 10 and have administrative rights on the user account. Also, the installation file is on C:/Temp/. What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess as to why the EULA isn't showing up.  Perhaps the download is corrupted or you have some graphics issue on the system on which you're installing it.  Can you run the installer on another computer simply to see if the EULA prompt shows up correctly?

To circumvent the issue entirely, assuming the download is not corrupted, you could use a response file installation.  This would allow you to install the product "headless," which would avoid the need to click through the graphical installer.

The [silent installation instructions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/t_c8bi_setupsilentinstallation.html) direct you to provide a response file when running the installation, a template for which can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/t_inst_response_templates.html).